# Distance between elements in 2D array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, 2d, distance

How can I determine the distance between 1's in a 2D array. For example, we have a 2D array like this:

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0
1 0 0 0
```

The algorithm has to output the distance from each element to the nearest 1. Like this:

```
2 3 2 1
1 2 1 0
0 1 2 1
0 1 2 2
```

How can I solve it ?

Comment: Is this problem copied from some programming challenge website? Else please show what you have already tried!!

Comment: Show what you have tried

Comment: Can you go diagonally as well?

Comment: @r20rock Yes it is a challenge and this is just a part of it. The original is a bit complicated.

Comment: @rath Probably no. You can see it from the output.

Comment: I haven't tried anything real yet and I don't have the solution.

Comment: What language may I ask? I posted an answer which was very language specific

Comment: I'm programming in C and a bit in C++, but nevermind. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate over the matrix and find the coordinates of all the 1's (x1, y1).  Then for each position in the cell (x2, y2), for all (x1, y1) in your list, find the minimum |x2 - x1| + |y2 - y1| (the Manhattan distance since it's a grid).

Comment: What do you mean by paths ?

Comment: shouldn't the minimum (x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1) be rather the absolute value of it ?

Comment: I think your answer is correct, thank you! But let's make it more difficult. There would be a given number K and you have to output for each cell minimum distance to K 1's. So for each cell you just find the nearest K 1's and ouput the distance of the furthermost 1 ? I'll edit the question.

Comment: @user2943215  sort the distance list and print kth element

Answer (score 2):

I liked this question, so I created a page online where you can try out solving it: 
http://www.learneroo.com/courses/29/nodes/221

The solution code is below, based on @manu-fatto's answer. The method `minArray` goes through the entire double array a few times, and each time it updates the minimum distance from each cell to a nearby 1 by picking the minimum value near it and adding 1.

```
import java.util.*;

class DistanceZ {   

static void minArray(int[][] square){
    int w = square.length;

    for(int times = 0; times<w; times++){
        for(int i =0; i<w; i++){
            for(int j=0;j<w;j++){
                square[i][j] = minCell(square, i, j);
            }
        }
    }       
    printArray(square);     
}
```

This method will calculate the minimum distance based on the current cell and its 4 neighbors:

```
static int minCell(int[][] square, int i, int j){
    //get the minimum of current cell and adjacent cells + 1.       
}
```

The next two methods are for input/output (see link for full code):

```
private static void printArray(int[][] square) {
    //print the Array
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //get input into arrays
}
}
```

Comment: +1 for "I liked this question", although we've programmed in every other language but the one Clu was using

Comment: @Isaac he didn't mention any language in question or tags, though now I see he mentioned it in comments. Anyways, you can use different languages on the page I linked to.

Comment: Good job, guys. I don't know why, but I like the Duncan's solution more.

Comment: @Clu, I had originally answered something like that, but I think manu-fatto's answer is more optimal, so my code follows that idea.

Comment: @Ari Would you mind posting your code or pseudo-code in C ? I can't really read your language, therefore I can't see which method is more optimal. Anyway, thanks for your work. Also, take a look at the edited question.

Comment: @Clu, I added some comments to explain the code. The Java code isn't that different from C code.

Comment: Where can I exactly find your full code ? Do I need to register on your website ?

Comment: @Clu, sorry, here's the full code in a Gist: https://gist.github.com/arikrak/7404970
(you need to register to do the challenge on the site.)

Answer (score 2):

Because you didn't specify the language :) here's a parallel version of the algorithm in Common Lisp:

```lisp
(ql:quickload :lparallel)
(defpackage :compute-distances (:use :cl :lparallel))
(in-package :compute-distances)

(defun positions (number matrix)
  (loop :for i :from 0 :below (array-dimension matrix 0)
     :nconc (loop :for j :from 0 :below (array-dimension matrix 1)
               :if (= number (aref matrix i j))
               :collect (cons i j))))

(defun find-neighbours (point points)
  (loop :with x := (car point) :and y := (cdr point)
     :for point :across points
     :unless (and (= x (car point)) (= y (cdr point)))
     :collect (let ((width (- x (car point)))
                    (height (- y (cdr point))))
                (sqrt (+ (* width width) (* height height))))))

(defun find-all-neighbours (number matrix)
  (let* ((positions (coerce (positions number matrix) 'vector))
         (*kernel* (make-kernel (length positions))))
    (pmap 'vector (lambda (point) (find-neighbours point number matrix))
          :parts (length positions) positions)))

(defparameter *test-matrix*
  (make-array '(4 4) :initial-contents
              '((0 0 0 0)
                (0 0 0 1)
                (1 0 0 0)
                (1 0 0 0))))

(find-all-neighbours 1 *test-matrix*)
;; #((3.1622777 3.6055512) (3.1622777 1.0) (3.6055512 1.0))
```

Comment: Well, I should specify the language next time :D Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a matrix with 0 where the 1 are located and a large number (larger then any possible distance) on the other cells. Then iterate over your matrix. In every cell put the minimum between the current value and the minimum of values of adjacent cells plus one. Iterate until you don't need any update.

Comment: So, for each cell I have to iterate over the whole matrix ?

Comment: Not quite. You will have to iterate over the whole matrix n times, where n is the 'distance' that will finally be stored in the most isolated cell.

Comment: "In every cell put the minimum between the current value and the minimum of values of adjacent cells plus one." I don't really understand this part.

Answer (score 0):

I know this may be just solving your homework, but I had to.

Here is an efficient way of solving your problem in JavaScript, I believe it is only O(n^2) (I'm a little rusty on O notation, and ignore the first loop which may be completed on data entry)

It works as follows

**Get each elements position**

```
for (var a=0,aa=arr.length; a<aa; a++) // this loop may be able to be done when data is read in
{
 result[a] = [];
 for (var b=0,bb=arr[a].length; b<bb; b++)
 {
  result[a][b] = -1;
  if(arr[a][b]==1)pos.push({x:a,y:b,dist:0});
 }
}
```

**Start looping through array**

Grabbing the first entry and removing it. In c++ you should use a queue

```
while(pos.length>0)
{
 var p = pos[0];
 pos.splice(0,1);
```

**Check if the distance hasn't already been set**

```
 if(result[p.x][p.y]==-1)
 {
```

**Check if the x and y coordinates are within the bounds of the array**

Add them to the end of the position array/queue, along with an extra distance unit

```
   var x = p.x+dx[a];
   var y = p.y+dy[a];
    if(x>=0&&x<result.length&&y>=0&&y<result[p.x].length)pos.push({x:x,y:y,dist:p.dist+1});
```

**Display output**

```
for (var a=0,aa=arr.length; a<aa; a++)
{
  console.log(result[a]);
}
```

**The full code:**

```
<script>
var arr = [
[0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0],
[1,0,0,0]];
var result = [];
var pos = [];

for (var a=0,aa=arr.length; a<aa; a++) // this loop may be able to be done when data is read in
{
 result[a] = [];
 for (var b=0,bb=arr[a].length; b<bb; b++)
 {
  result[a][b] = -1;
  if(arr[a][b]==1)pos.push({x:a,y:b,dist:0});
 }
}
var dx = [-1,0,0,1];
var dy = [0,1,-1,0];

while(pos.length>0)
{
 var p = pos[0];
 pos.splice(0,1);
 if(result[p.x][p.y]==-1)
 {
  result[p.x][p.y] = p.dist;
  for(var a=0; a<4; a++)
  {
   var x = p.x+dx[a];
   var y = p.y+dy[a];
   if(x>=0&&x<result.length&&y>=0&&y<result[p.x].length)pos.push({x:x,y:y,dist:p.dist+1});
  }
 }
}
for (var a=0,aa=arr.length; a<aa; a++)
{
  console.log(result[a]);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use BFS by first adding all '1's into Q, and consider these cells as 0 in 'Cost' matrix (initialize other cells with n).
- Then try to dequeue x (i.e. pair(i,j)) until Q is empty.
- Update the neighbors in 'Cost' matrix with value 'x+1' only if is smaller than current value.
- Add updated neighbors into Q.